# Setting overlays above polylines in google maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have been trying to set overlay above polylines using zindex. I have tried using

```
overlay.getPanes().overlayLayer.style['zIndex'] = 1001;
```

and setting zindex of polylines to 1. Does anyone know the correct method to have the overlays appear above polylines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting it on a higher pane, 'floatPane' being the highest.

Information on panes: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Initializing